# Как удалить картинку из бд на странице

Tags: php, ajax

Есть картинка на сайте, мне нужно через ajax или post удалить картинки при клике на нее. Подскажите как мне реализовать это на ajax.
HTML код

```
<img id="output_<?=$k?>" data-id="<?=$img[id]?>" class="modal_images" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="<?= $img['name'] ?>">
```

В Бд хранится путь картинки. В бд есть таблица images с 3 полями, `id, name, tovar_id`

класс mg принадлежит картинке, при клике на картинку происходит действие описанное ниже:

```
$(".mg").on("click", function(e) {
    var id = this.dataset.id;
    var src = this.attributes.src;//получаем id текущей кнопки
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/task.php", {id:id},function(result) {  //передача id
        alert(result);
        //$(".mg").hide()
    });
});
```

**php**

```
$c="DELETE FROM `images` WHERE id=$_REQUEST['id'] ";
$query1=$dbh->prepare($c);
$query1->execute();
```

Comment: В вопросе фигурирует база данных, какая? Хранятся ли в ней записи об изображении? В какой таблице?

Comment: А зачем вообще хранить картинки в бд? Есть же папка для этого.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно сделать такую логику
**1)** при нажатии на картинку ловишь ее id,которое совпадает с ее id в бд.
**2)**Формируешь запрос,который выглядит примерно так.код ниже вешаешь на обработчик клика картинки

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".modal_images", function() {
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "deleteimg.php",
      data: "id="+idimg,//где idimg переменная,из 1 пункта
      success: function(result){
        alert( "Все окей");
      }
    });
});
```

**3)** на странице `deleteimg.php`,получаешь переменную $idimg=$_REQUEST['id']
**4)** формируешь запрос на удаление с условием `where id=$idimg`

Comment: попробовал, не получилось. Если разница если я хочу удалить картинки через модальное окно. То есть есть таблица при нажатии на строку мне открывается модальное окно в подробном ввиде с картинками и оттуда я уже хочу удалить их.

Comment: не могли проверить мой скрипт на правильность ?

Comment: 1)ошибки выводит? Что выводит это  `alert(result);` 2) Попробуйте в php файле сделать просто `echo`, это позволить проверить работоспособность `ajax`.3) Затем проверьте получает ли ваш php обработчик переменную (тоже ,к примеру, выведите ее) если это работает ,будем искать ошибку дальше